# Preventing overflow:hidden from cropping text

Tags: css, overflow

I have a table of repeating rows (with different content) each containing the following same cells:

```
<td><img src="/images/a_photo.jpg" height="150" width="225"></td>
<td class="right">
<div class="stuff">
<h4>Two or three words</h4><h5>Two or three more words</h5>
<p>Quite alot of words</p>
</div>
<div>
Always a single line of known height
</div>
</td>
```

The height of the (td class="right") is set by the height of the photo in the first (td). This results in a fixed available height for the (div class="stuff"). However the height of the space given to the (h4) and (h5) varies because sometimes the  runs onto the second row and other times only the (h5).

I know that I could control the cropping of the (p) to only show complete lines by making line-height an exact fraction of the available height. But with the available height being variable, I sometimes get half a line of text, which looks ugly and wrong.

The simplified CSS is

```
h4{font-size:1.5em}
h5{font-size:0.9em}
td.right{overflow:hidden}
```

Is there any way to limit the (p) to whole lines (vertically), or am I asking the impossible?

Comment: Dynamic content with static heights :( What happens when it goes to 3 lines? Or when the screen becomes smaller and the 2 lines of text becomes 3? I would let your content determine the height of the cell, or if the static height is an absolute must then add a scrollbar to the `div.stuff`

Comment: Yes, I know it's not ideal but both variable heights and scrollbars are ugly too. Perhaps I have to make all text (including h4 and h5) the same height. But then that's another design compromise :(

Comment: do you mean you want to fit all your text into a particular height or you dont mind if the container (p) changes depending on the contents inside it?

Comment: I have a fixed space available for the (h4), (h5) and (p). I can accept that the last part of the text will not be visible, as long as the lines that are visible are complete ie not showing just the tops of the letters. In an ideal world the cropped text would end with an ellipsis, but that's probably asking far too much.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by another route.

The biggest problem as it stood was that the (h4) and (h5) text ran over into a second line, but that second line was sometimes the height of (h4) and sometimes the height of (h5). This changed the space available for the (p) text by about half a line so I was liable to get the top half of a line of text, sometimes.

I've dropped the (h4) and written all the first part in (h5). This means the first two rows are always the same height, and I can then tailor the remaining space to always show complete rows of the (p) text.

This is only applicable to fairly narrow screens (tablets in portait orientation) so the responsive CSS just changes the height of the (h4) to be the same as (h5) when the screen width is below the threshold.